# Why html method is returning undefined in this case?

Tags: jquery

I can't figure why the html() method is returning undefined in this case even though I am sure it is there

```
        if (e.charCode == 13) {

            var $array = $('span.spOption');
            var item = $array.eq(currentItem);
            console.log(item.html());

        }
```

spOptions returns N span elements

Comment: You need to append the $array to item. Here you are just assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Where does `currentItem` come from?

Comment: current item is just a int var controlling the index

Comment: @ThePoet are you sure it's defined? If so - where? Is this in a for or while loop?

Comment: can you share what $array outputs? console.log($array)

Comment: eq is zero based the issue can be there, tried currentItem-1 ?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not getting anything in your $array by having a bad selector.  Maybe spelling span.isOption?  If you are truly getting an array back, you should get something.. Example var x = ["one", "two"]; $(x).eq(0);//returns "one"

Comment: you are totally right, it was empty and I didn't realize, there was code before it that was cleaning it, make your comment an answer and I will accept it. thanks.

Comment: I added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're not getting anything in your $array by having a bad selector. Maybe spelling span.isOption? If you are truly getting an array back, you should get something.. Example:

```
var x = ["one", "two"]; 
$(x).eq(0);  //returns "one"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't make sense for an inline element like span to have any HTML or children. Try using text().